# Display image based on condition

Tags: image, jasper-reports, conditional-statements

Below code did not worked, I am getting an error.

```
<image>
  <reportElement x="42" y="101" width="22" height="23"/>
  <printWhenExpression>($F{booleanConditon} ? <![CDATA[$P{path} + "checkBox.png"]] : <![CDATA[$P{path} + "unCheckBox.png"]]>)</printWhenExpression>
</image>
```

And the error message is

```
Error loading the report template:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 730; columnNumber: 22; cvc- complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'printWhenExpression'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":box, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":graphicElement, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":imageExpression, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":anchorNameExpression, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":hyperlinkReferenceExpression, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":hyperlinkWhenExpression, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":hyperlinkAnchorExpression, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":hyperlinkPageExpression, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":hyperlinkTooltipExpression, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":hyperlinkParameter}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your XML is invalid.
The element `printWhenExpression` cannot be a direct child of `image`. It should be a child of `reportElement`.

Example:

```
<image>
  <reportElement x="42" y="101" width="22" height="23">
    <printWhenExpression>($F{booleanConditon} ? <![CDATA[$P{path} + "checkBox.png"]] : <![CDATA[$P{path} + "unCheckBox.png"]]>)</printWhenExpression>
  </reportElement>
</image>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Image Expression** as below

Example :

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1 ? "img/watermark_firstpage.png" : "img/watermark_otherpage.png"]]></imageExpression>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark **all** of the expression inside  `<![CDATA[..code...]]>` so that the xml parser will interpret it purely as textual data, the evaluation of the expression will be done by the jasper report engine.

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{booleanConditon} ? $P{path} + "checkBox.png" : $P{path} + "unCheckBox.png")]]></printWhenExpression>
```

Hence the evaluation process, first parsing of xml (sax parser), then parsing of your expression (jasper report engine)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. Solution is as bellow. You can take one image but
I have two images checked.png and unchecked.png. 
I have made query to database and fetched the value of the field 'checkAsIsFlag'. This field contains 'Y'(Checked) or 'N'(Unchecked) as a text value. I will show an image checked.png if checkAsIsFlag='Y' and  unchecked.png if checkAsIsFlag='N'.

I have placed both images on design page one above the other (same location in pixels). And written expression in the 'Print When Expression' field, check Reference Image.

Short source code is as bellow:

```
        <image>
            <reportElement x="30" y="7" width="25" height="25" uuid="afe9a678-28a4-40d2-bc61-82b49fb904d9">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{checkasisflag}.equals("Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["http://localhost:8080/studentreport/images/checked.png"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>

        <image>
            <reportElement x="30" y="7" width="25" height="25" uuid="a993026c-430e-4f56-9531-3baaa0de11f4">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{checkasisflag}.equals("N")]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["http://localhost:8080/studentreport/images/unchecked.png"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
```

[Reference Image Eclipse IDE Jasper Report Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jfse.jpg)